# Is there any way to move the cursor position of a linked list in constant time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a linked list like this:

> Head->A->B->C->D->Tail.

There can be `N (1<N<10^5)` items in the list.
The current cursor position is, cursor->B which is 2 if we think like an array.
I have to perform the following operation on my list:

- insert x characters in the list at the cursor position and update the
  cursor.
- delete `y (y < N`) characters starting from the
  cursor position and update the cursor.
- move the cursor to a specific position within in the list.

I want all this operation in constant time. 
Can anyone kindly help by suggesting any data structure model?

Comment: Iterating/moving through a linked list cannot be done in constant time, that's always the biggest drawback of a linked list (and the advantage of arrays)

Comment: Are you sure that is possible? Moving to a position in constant time requires an index of sorts. Manipulating (insert/delete) would require you to update said index for all following elements. I would be impressed if that was possible in constant time. Why would anybody still use lists or arrays if a combination of both advantages were available?

Comment: If I use a container data structure like an array, then the complexity of insertion and deletion will be O(n). Is there any way to mix both array and list or anything to get all these operations in constant time?

Comment: In what scenario are you using the data structure? If you want to store a text document, Piece table may help - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piece_table

Comment: If there had been an "O(1) everything" container, we would use nothing else. Now it is a compromise where you have to choose the closest match. With a data set as "small" as 10^5, the performance of a `std::string` or a `std::vector<char>` would probably surprise you.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. Searching / iterating is linear in complexity - O(n). If you want a constant complexity, you need to use the different data structure. Since you are using C++, you should utilize one from the [Containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: If I use a container data structure like an array, then the complexity of insertion and deletion will be O(n). Is there any way to mix both to get all these operations in constant time?

Comment: @Gangcil - There is no way to have your cake and eat it too

Answer (score 2):

If the data can be sorted then by using "skip lists" a speed up can be achieved.

The principle is that extra pointers are used to skip ahead.

> skip list is a data structure that allows fast search within an ordered sequence of elements. Fast search is made possible by maintaining a linked hierarchy of subsequences, with each successive subsequence skipping over fewer elements than the previous one ...

[wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

> Therefore, with O(√n) extra space, we are able to reduce the time complexity to O(√n).

[Skip-list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/skip-list/)

Comment: That particular approach seems to work only with the sorted lists. You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: A skip list by it's definition has to be sorted, to work.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not possible to use the linked list for that. As said before a linked list has a linear complexity.

You can try to use a more complex data structure like a hash as a lookup-container for the items in  your list, which has a complexity of - O(n). Instead of storing the items itself the stored item can contain a pointer / index showing to the next item. But you have to keep in mind that the deletion will be still expensive because when removing one item you have to refresh the links showing to this item as well, So the item itself will need to know, if any other items are pointing to it.